# How to dynamically select different branches in Keras model, based on the input?

Tags: keras

Suppose I have a training batch of size 10, and I need to use a different branch of my keras model for each input in the batch. Is this possible? Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Aim is to build dynamic computational graphs.I found a method using TensorFlow Fold (https://github.com/tensorflow/fold). Is something similar possible using keras?